# How To Create a List of Interactive Items

Tags: android

How can I create a list of items that allows users to click each individual item. For example,

Apple
Banana
Pineapple

User can click any one of these and then I will query a website and deliver more specific information about the clicked fruit. Is it possible to do without creating another view or action, i.e. just changing the information using setText() with checkedtextview?

Comment: sorry, I had no idea what that meant. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Seem that you understood meanwhile, thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView or ListActivity with an onItemClickListener(), and an another Activity for showing the details.